# Problems doing DNS from my server

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

When I do `service bind9 status`, it tells me the following

```
named[983]: managed-keys-zone: unable to synchronize managed keys: unexpected error
named[983]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
named[983]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
named[983]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
named[983]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
named[983]: zone midomain.com/IN: loaded serial 2017061000
named[983]: all zones loaded
named[983]: running zone midomain.com/IN: sending notifies (serial 2017061000)
named[983]: client 201.235.234.30#55016: received notify for zone 'midomain.com'
```

The log `/var/log/syslog` reads:

```
 the working directory is not writable
named[983]: managed-keys.bind.jnl: create: permission denied
named[983]: managed-keys-zone: sync_keyzone:dns_journal_open -> unexpected error
named[983]: managed-keys-zone: unable to synchronize managed keys: unexpected error
```

How can I get bind9 to start and run correctly?

Answer (score 0):

What user is bind running as? Is it in a chroot jail? What OS?

The issue is that it cannot create the journal file (`managed-keys.bind.jnl` file), and cannot open the `managed-keys-zone` file. Is selinux on?

To check where these files are located, run (as root) the following command:

```
find / -name "managed-keys-zone"
```

Then, check the permissions on that file:

```
ls -lh <path from above>
```

You should see permissions listed with up to 10 characters (sometimes 11). Ignore the first letter; that will be a `-`, `l` or `d`. The next three are permissions for the USER listed (**R**ead, **W**rite, E**x**ecute). The next three are for the GROUP listed, then the last three are for Everyone Else.

Check who owns it from the `ls` command above - is it owned by root or another name (i.e. bind).

Comment: Sorry for not putting it before I'm running on bind9 ubuntu distribution 16.01, this I'm doing as root user, the reality is that I do not understand what can happen if it is a permissions problem or another type of problem

Comment: `Thanks for the previous answer in this way me di account that there is no such file/file... and I also believe that file`

Comment: @PablitoMaugeri I'm sorry, but I don't understand the last half of your recent comment?

Comment: sorry not good speak English... recently I realized that I do not believe that file... It seems to me that you try to create and you can not do it

Comment: Building on Luke's answer/comments:  The root of your problem is this message ' the working directory is not writable'. Please post the output of the following 2 commands: 'ls -al /var/cache/bind' and 'ps -ef | grep named'.  It's likely the owner of the named process cannot write to /var/cache/bind at all.

Comment: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 jun 28 12:21 /var/cache/bind -> /etc/bind
pablo@mydomain:~$ ps -ef | grep named
bind       980     1  0 jun28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/named -f -u bind
pablo     2574  2553  0 00:00 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto named `

Comment: This suggests that '/etc/bind/' must be writable by the 'bind' user.  The following 2 commands  can make that happen: 'sudo chown root.bind /etc/bind' and 'sudo chmod 775 /etc/bind'.  Then restart the service. (The above commands set the owner and permissions to match what I got doing a fresh bind9 install on an older  Ubuntu 14.04 test server)

Comment: `Thank you very much for the reply  the truth that had already tried it before... but still the same problem gave him permission 775 and chown root.bind folders etc and /var/cache/bind ` @Brandon Xavier

Comment: What command are you using to restart the service? Have you tried invoking the command with `/etc/init.d/bind9 restart`?

Answer (score 0):

Add following options to `named.conf`:

```
options {
...
dnssec-enable yes;
dnssec-validation auto;
managed-keys-directory "/etc/namedb/dynamic/";
...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case file and directory owner is incorrect. follow bellow command to fix it:

```
sudo chown -R root:bind  /var/cache/bind
sudo chown -R root:bind  /var/cache/bind/managed-keys.bind
sudo chown -R root:bind  /var/cache/bind/managed-keys.bind.jnl
```

For see reference [click here](https://servercode.ca/how-to-fix-bind-error-managed-keys-bind-jnl-open-permission-denied/).

You can restart named.service without get any error now:

```
sudo systemctl restart named.service
```

and check status logs:

```
sudo systemctl status named.service
```